# Javascript Recharts dynamically creating XAxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Im trying to create a bar chart using recharts for the data below. the chart will create 2 Page A's on the x axis rather than put the the second pair of bars  to the existing Page A. is there anyway this can be done?

```
<BarChart width={730} height={250} data={data}>
  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
```

```
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Page A",
    "uv": 4000,
    "pv": 2400
  },
  {
    "name": "Page B",
    "uv": 3000,
    "pv": 1398
  },
  {
    "name": "Page C",
    "uv": 2000,
    "pv": 9800
  },
  {
    "name": "Page D",
    "uv": 2780,
    "pv": 3908
  },
  {
    "name": "Page E",
    "uv": 1890,
    "pv": 4800
  },
  {
    "name": "Page F",
    "uv": 2390,
    "pv": 3800
  },
  {
    "name": "Page A",
    "uv": 3490,
    "pv": 4300
  }
]
```